# missing pagespeed.conf file

Tags: linux, optimization, mod-pagespeed

I've used many different resources in an attempt to install mod_pagespeed on a CentOS WHM/cPanel server.

Mostly this: https://github.com/pagespeed/cpanel

All resources I've looked at suggest that after successful installation I should have a configuration file called pagespeed.conf.

There are a few different locations that the articles suggest it should be in, most of them symbolic links to the same place, but none of them contain the file!

https://ismodpagespeedworking.com suggests that the installation was successful and can see the headers and a manual check using

```
curl -Is http://the-website/ | grep X-Mod-Pagespeed
```

sees the correct headers too.

I'm stumped because the .conf file does't seem to be on the server and I've used locate to verify this.

If anyone else has experienced this and can provide any clues I would be most grateful.